# Can an official transit through the UK without a transit visa if not on official mission?

Tags: uk, transit, passports, officials

I have just read on [this GOV document](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/740080/UK_Visa_requirements_Sept_2018.pdf):

> Holders of diplomatic or official passports may transit without a visa

Is this information still valid or is it expired? If it is, is it applicable to transit for non-official reasons? It is not mentioned on the gov.uk website that deals with visas. I do hold an official passport.

Comment: Are you referring to the notes on the top right of the document? It looks to me that item 4, which you quote, relates to Indian nationals. At the top of the document it states that all nationals of countries listed in red underlined need visas to enter or transit the UK. Kenya is one of the countries listed in red.

Comment: I would think your own country would forbid you to use your official passport for any non-official purpose.

Comment: @NateEldredge that isn't necessarily true, however.

Comment: @Traveller in the current version of the document, at least, which is from July (six months after the question was asked), it also applies to Vietnamese nationals.

Answer (score 1):

On the [UK visa check](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india) it states:

> For official diplomatic or government business (including transit through the UK)

Therefore, the UK would also not accept this passport if you're not on a mission. So the normal visa rules from the country you come from will apply to you.

Comment: But the visa check you link to also specifies Indian nationality.

Comment: @phoog TL;DR The form questions will still be the same, unless he is fully exempt which I presume he wouldn't be asking